# Is there a tool in arctoolbox for IDistanceOp.CostPathasPolyline?

Tags: arcobjects, distance, arctoolbox, geoprocessing-framework

Almost all the methods in [IDistanceOp](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDistanceOp_Interface/00400000003s000000/) have a corresponding tool in the [Distance Toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/An_overview_of_the_Distance_tools/009z00000014000000/) Spatial Analyst Toolbox.  However, I can't find anything in the toolbox for [IDistanceOp.CostPathasPolyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00400000004w000000).

Does anyone know if such a tool exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool does not exist in the toolbox, but you can use cost path, then [raster to polyline](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000009000000) to get the same result (in theory)